# Window often loses focus in Windows 7 on Lenovo B580

Tags: windows-7, lenovo-laptop, window-focus

I have a new laptop Lenovo B580, with Windows 7. As I write, the window sometimes loses focus and I cannot write anymore. Or it happens that the cursor moves within the window. It behaves like is a random "click" - when I move the mouse/touchpad then, the text is selected.

It happens when I use mouse - and I really don't touch the touchpad :-) And it also happens when I use the touchpad only. Strange.

When using mouse, I tried to disable the touchpad with the Fn key, the B580 displays that the touchpad is disabled, but it still works.

**EDIT:**

1. the problem is not in the mouse, the problem still appears when mouse is unplugged.
2. there are no "overlay" apps in the tray - only the standard ones, which came preinstalled with the computer - adding a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Ok, what are the apps (2nd in top row, 1st in 2nd row)? The others I recognize. btw only the last two apps on the 2nd row and 1st on the 3rd row are 'standard'.  oh and I would see what Windows Update wants too (the middle icon 2nd row).

Comment: @cjb110, this is ESET NOD32 Antivirus. I'll try to install the updates, but I doubt this will help... just general windows and IE updates.

Answer (score 0):

If your sure its not hardware, then it could be a background program, taking the focus away.

I would check task manager, see if anything stands out as not belonging, and run a AV scan just to be safe.

If that doesn't help then try closing any program that adds any kind of overlay type affect to Windows.  It could well be one of the bundled bloat-ware apps.

Comment: thanks @cjb... 1) how can I make sure it's not hardware? 2) what you mean by "overlay-type affect"? My computer and OS is brand new, and I use it very reasonably, so I can almost 100% exclude the possibility of virus or malware.

Comment: by overlay, I mean a program that doesn't appear in a normal Window, i.e. like a quick launch menu, things like that.  A lot of manufactures include apps that do this, so you could try going into msconfig and removing some of the startup items.

Comment: as for being sure its not hardware, I'd disconnect the mouse, and just use the trackpad.  I know it'll be awkward being certain that your not accidentally touching it, but you need to eliminate anything that could simulate a click.  Also have you been into the BIOS, there might be a option to disable the trackpad in there too.

Comment: cjb110, I tried to disconnect the mouse and looked at the software, but it didn't help. Please see my edited question. Thanks! P.S.: I have not tried to disable the touchpad yet though.

Answer (score 0):

On the Lenovo Z70-80 I had a similar issue of randomly loosing focus even when sitting across the room not touching anything.

I found out that this has been a problem with several Lenovo laptops. Some models simply get shipped with a bad driver for the touchpad and even with the touchpad "deactivated" the driver was causing some issue that led to seemingly random loss of focus on my active windows.

I manually found and updated my touchpad driver and the problem has been gone ever since.

Answer (score 0):

When I have this problem, I use this focus-monitor.exe that I found.  It should tell you which program/process is stealing your focus, and help lead you to your solution:

https://mega.nz/file/4Y8nnbSa#Pnw97sQz8bRM_bXjlrcYT_HGiaBd4kdY_6DNq0T7FWE